# REST API データ登録要求時、リミット発生した場合の適切な HTTP レスポンスコードは？

Tags: http, rest

以下のようなケースの場合、適切なHTTP レスポンスコードの番号をご教授いただけますでしょうか。

レスポンスコードの一覧を覗きましたが、何が適切なのか分かりませんでした。

想定ケース:

- (POST) REST API 新規登録要求
  リミット発生：要求は正常だが、登録項目数上限の場合

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`400 Bad Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)が良いと思います。

前提として、クライアントサイドの不備によるエラーなので、[`4xx`](https://www.itmanage.co.jp/column/http-www-request-response-statuscode/#anc004)を返すべきです。
登録項目数上限を超えている意味で不正な要求のため、`4xx`および詳細なメッセージを返してPOSTするデータを整形してリトライしてもらう意図を伝えます。

`4xx`の中で`400`以外にふさわしいコードがあればそちらを採用できますが、適していそうな[`413 Payload Too Large`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413)はペイロードに関するエラーなのでベストマッチとは言えないように感じます。

[Microsoft REST API Guidelines](https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines)の[16.2.1. Error response](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#1621-error-response)が良くまとまっていますので引用します。

**引用ここから**

### 16.2.1. Error response

Services MUST provide an error response if a caller requests an unsupported feature found in the feature allow list. The error response MUST be an HTTP status code from the 4xx series, indicating that the request cannot be fulfilled. Unless a more specific error status is appropriate for the given request, services SHOULD return "400 Bad Request" and an error payload conforming to the error response guidance provided in the Microsoft REST API Guidelines. Services SHOULD include enough detail in the response message for a developer to determine exactly what portion of the request is not supported.

Example:

```
GET https://api.contoso.com/v1.0/people?$orderBy=name HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
```

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorUnsupportedOrderBy",
    "message": "Ordering by name is not supported." 
  }
}
```

**引用ここまで**

類例として[AWS S3のエラーコード](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-error-responses.html)では、`LimitExceededException`や`InvalidParameterValueException`の場合に`400 Bad Request`を返します。
なお、この回答は類似質問[Which response code for resources max. limit in REST API?の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761341/8248751)をとても参考にしました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
また参考ページやAWSでの事例など、とても分かりやすい内容で助かりました。